# How to check if array contains specific object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, indexof

I am trying to check if array of objects contain a specific object or object with specific property.

```js
var mainArray = [
{name:"Yahya", age:"29"},
{name:"Ahmed", age:"19"},
{name:"Mohamed", age:"10"},
{name:"Ali", age:"32"},
{name:"Mona", age:"25"},
{name:"Shady", age:"62"},
{name:"Reem", age:"11"},
{name:"Marwa", age:"52"}
]

var myObject = {name:"Yahya", age:"29"};

function check() {
if (mainArray.indexOf(myObject) > -1) {
  console.log("true")
  return true;
} else {
  console.log('false')
  return false;
}
};
```

```html
<button onClick="check()">Check</button>
```

here's however the object is same as one of array objects . but it's return false .
I tried includes, also not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to check if the array of objects contain that specific object then you can use `Array.some`

```js
var mainArray = [{
    name: "Yahya",
    age: "29"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahmed",
    age: "19"
  },
  {
    name: "Mohamed",
    age: "10"
  },
  {
    name: "Ali",
    age: "32"
  },
  {
    name: "Mona",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    name: "Shady",
    age: "62"
  },
  {
    name: "Reem",
    age: "11"
  },
  {
    name: "Marwa",
    age: "52"
  }
]

var myObject = {
  name: "Yahya",
  age: "29"
};

let ans = mainArray.some(function(arrVal) {
  return myObject.name === arrVal.name;
});
console.log(ans)
```

You can also use `filter` method.In this case it will return an array of the matched elements. Check the length of the returned array to verify if it contains desired elements

```js
var mainArray = [{
    name: "Yahya",
    age: "29"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahmed",
    age: "19"
  },
  {
    name: "Mohamed",
    age: "10"
  },
  {
    name: "Ali",
    age: "32"
  },
  {
    name: "Mona",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    name: "Shady",
    age: "62"
  },
  {
    name: "Reem",
    age: "11"
  },
  {
    name: "Marwa",
    age: "52"
  }
]

var myObject = {
  name: "Yahya",
  age: "29"
};

let newAns = mainArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item.name === myObject.name && item.age === myObject.age
})
if (newAns.length > 0) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Array` method given by `findIndex`, we can do simply something like below

```js
var mainArray = [
  {name:"Yahya", age:"29"},
  {name:"Ahmed", age:"19"},
  {name:"Mohamed", age:"10"},
  {name:"Ali", age:"32"},
  {name:"Mona", age:"25"},
  {name:"Shady", age:"62"},
  {name:"Reem", age:"11"},
  {name:"Marwa", age:"52"}
]

var myObject = {name:"Yahya", age:"29"};

function check() {
  if (mainArray.findIndex(obj => obj.name == myObject.name && obj.age == myObject.age) > -1) {
    console.log("true")
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('false')
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
<button onClick="check()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `some` elements of that array are the same as the object you are checking against when stringified, like so:

```
mainArray.some(e => JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

```js
function check() {
 console.log(mainArray.some(e => JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(myObject)))
};


let mainArray = [{
    name: "Yahya",
    age: "29"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahmed",
    age: "19"
  },
  {
    name: "Mohamed",
    age: "10"
  },
  {
    name: "Ali",
    age: "32"
  },
  {
    name: "Mona",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    name: "Shady",
    age: "62"
  },
  {
    name: "Reem",
    age: "11"
  },
  {
    name: "Marwa",
    age: "52"
  }
]

let myObject = {
  name: "Yahya",
  age: "29"
};
```

```html
<button onClick="check()">Check myObject</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf will try to find the object in the collection using the basic comparison mechanism. Try to run:
`{name:"Yahya", age:"29"} === {name:"Yahya", age:"29"}`
in javascript console and you'll get false, since these are 2 different objects, created using the same string literals.

I believe you should read more info on Objects in OOP in general.

To check if a collection contains an element with the tester function provided use Array.prototype.some():

```js
var mainArray = [
    {name:"Yahya", age:"29"},
    {name:"Ahmed", age:"19"},
    {name:"Mohamed", age:"10"},
    {name:"Ali", age:"32"},
    {name:"Mona", age:"25"},
    {name:"Shady", age:"62"},
    {name:"Reem", age:"11"},
    {name:"Marwa", age:"52"}
];

var myObject = {name: "Yahya", age: "29"};

function check(object) {
    return mainArray.some(function(element) {
        return element.name === object.name && element.age === object.age;
    })
}

console.log(check(myObject));
```

Notice that the comparison is done using "===", if you have age in your mainArray collection set as string and in myObject - as number, use "==" for age comparison instead.